# Angular2 - Put a component between elements

Tags: json, angular, angular2-template

i have a json-structure which dictates a rich-text, which I create using angulars renderer and add it directly to the dom like the following:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'formatted-text',
 templateUrl: 'formatted-text.component.html'
})
export class FormattedTextComponent implements OnInit {
 nativeElement: Node;

 constructor(private renderer: Renderer,
          private elementRef: ElementRef,
          private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
          private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {

      this.nativeElement = elementRef.nativeElement;
  }
  private renderPart(part, parent) {
    if ('plain' == part.tag) {
      this.renderer.createText(parent, part.content);
    }
    else {
      if (part.content instanceof Array) {
        let nativeElement = this.renderer.createElement(parent, part.tag);
        for (let e of part.content) {
          this.renderPart(e, nativeElement);
        }
      }
      else if (typeof part.content == "object") {
        if (part.tag == 'include') {
          this.addElement(part.content);
        }
        else {
          let nativeElement = this.renderer.createElement(parent, part.tag);
          this.renderPart(part.content, nativeElement);
        }
      }
      else {
        let nativeElement = this.renderer.createElement(parent, part.tag);
        this.renderer.setText(nativeElement, part.content);
      }
   }
 }
```

The JSON-Structure looks like this:

```
[
        {
          "tag": "b",
          "content": "Hello World, "
        },
        {
          "tag": "include",
          "content": {
            "className": "link-internal",
            "element": {
              "link": "/test/en-US",
              "text": "Click Here",
              "target": "_blank",
              "follow": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "tag": "plain",
          "content": "This is plain text "
        },
        {
          "tag": "table",
          "content": {
            "tag": "tr",
            "content": [
              {
                "tag": "td",
                "content": "table cell"
              },
              {
                "tag": "td",
                "content": "table cell 2"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "tag": "u",
          "content": {
            "tag": "i",
            "content": "multiple formats are possible"
          }
        }
      ]
```

Creating the formatted text, works like this. My problem is, to include components. As you can see in the JSON-Structure I'd like to include a component called "internal-link" which renders links and so on. Since the elements dont have their own view, I dont see how I would add a component to them.

My idea would be to create a component for plain text and so on, and just stack those components together. This seems like a lot of components, just for formatted text.

If anybody has a good idea how to do this properly, I'd appreciate a it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use ComponentFactoryResolver to load the component dynamically and insert it in your template.

Comment: To add a component you need a viewRef, but I dont see how I would add the component to the view which is already populated with other elements. Loading the component is no problem, but adding it into the dom is the hard part...